# Jquery-ui - combining Sortable with Droppable - droppable function fires when sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable unordered lists on a page, which are populated via webservice calls.

One of the lists is populated by the other, via jQuery-UI draggable/droppable.

When an item is dropped onto the 2nd list, the droppable function is called, which updates the database. This works fine.

However, I also want this list to be sortable. When I sort the list, both the Sortable and Droppable functions are invoked, and I only want sortable.

How can I sort the 2nd list and not have droppable also invoked?

Code:

```
$("#MyDiv1 li").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#MyDiv2",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: function () {
       //other stuff here
    }
}).disableSelection();


$("#MyDiv2").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul",
    revert: true,
    update: function (event, ui) {
        //update new sort through webservice call
    }
}).droppable({
          tolerance: 'pointer',
          drop: function (event, ui) {
              //add dropped item through web service call
          }
      })
```

Comment: Please provide sufficient code to reproduce the issue such as `html`, css or a minimal demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You down voted a 5 month old question, that is answered in the comments, because there isn't html along with the jquery code? The first line of my question states what is in the html and the code provided is more than enough to anyone that understands jquery to know what's going on. Also, you may want to do the same in your own questions as many do not contain the exact related html or a jsfiddle that someone can copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to find a work around, but I'm sure there's a better way.

Under the drop function, I added a check to the parent ID to make sure it wasn't MyDiv2

```
  var ParentID = ui.draggable.context.parentNode.id;

  if (ParentID != "MyDiv2") {

    //drop code
  }
```